# Using VoIP from Android via GPRS?

Tags: voip, gprs

Is it possible to use VoIP over gprs from an Android phone? Either using a SIP client or Skype?

Comment: Do you consider Google Voice a VoIP client? It is currently open to join

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of sip clients available such as Sipdroid, CSipSimple, and Linphone.  Sipdroid includes an option to create a pbxes.org account linked to your Google Voice account, allowing you to make and receive calls to and from PSTN numbers for free, assuming you are in the US.  (After the account is created, any sip client can be used with the pbxes.org account.)

If you want to setup your own Asterisk server, you can [configure the trunking with Google Voice](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Calling+using+Google) yourself.  Or you can use any other VOIP service that provides SIP/PSTN trunking.

An alternative option is GrooVe IP, which is a Google Talk client with voice support.  This uses XMPP/Jingle directly between your android device and Google Talk/Voice.  The free version only supports WLAN networking; the paid version works over mobile networks.

Answer (score 1):

There a quite a few SIP clients last time I looked, but you need some sort of ID you have to purchase elsewhere to make use of them. Skype is supposedly coming soon and I think is available right now for Verizon Android phones.

Ditto Fring. Its a great app and probably one of the easier ones to use. Plus you can do video conferencing with Fring.

Comment: it is available for verizon, but they have some weird deal where you can only use the voice stuff over the 3G network, no wifi.

Comment: Oh thats right, I forgot about that. Yea, I would be surprised if someone didn't come out with a root app that allows voice over wifi, or if the carriers opened up Skype.

Answer (score 0):

[Try Fring](http://www.fring.com/default.php)  it is all in one, Unfortunately they do not support Skype anymore, But ther is SIP, Gmail, MSN and many others.